# How do you get/set the scroll position in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dhtml

I have a table that has a fixed header and a scrollable body.  I want to know the scroll position in the table so that I can reference it on postback and set it to where the user was before postback.  I would prefer JQuery to do this, but Javascript is fine too.  Im not sure how much code to post here because Im not sure if the problem is that I just dont know the code to do this, or the code I have (css) is interfering with the solutions I have tried.

Any ideas where to start?  Is there a method that does this?  Ive tried putting this (table style="overflow:auto; height:150" onclick="alert(this.scrollTop)") in the table but it always returns 0.

Ive also tried various JQuery calls as well.  They all return 0.

Comment: Show your real html markup. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) it!

Comment: Is your table actually scrolled? [Works for me here](http://jsfiddle.net/w7yuH/1/).

Comment: Ive never seen JSFiddle!  Very cool.  Let me see if I can figure out how to put my code out there.  Ive seen plenty of examples that work with scrolling divs or list.  Im trying to do a scrolling table with frozen headers.  I dont want to put the table in a div as that seems to be a little cumbersome.

Comment: I put it up on JSFiddle.  For this example, I put an alert in the onclick of the table that returns the scrollTop position.  I know this doesn't work, but Im not sure why.   http://jsfiddle.net/rahkim/TegrJ/8/

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know (and I am dealing with this kind of stuff everyday), native tables can't handle scrollbars as your describing. I think that probably, your table actually contains a div or other container, which is actually scrolling the table cells. Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/mBDjx/46/

I recomend you to inspect your code using the browser developer tools (usually F12) and check if it is only a table, or another element the one which is generating the scroll.

If you realize that is is a div, just check the .scrollTop attribute of the div instead of doing it on the table :-)

Hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

It is the tbody that is scrolling and that is what you need to test.  this.scrollTop is referring to the table , and the top of the table is not changing position.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I was trying to figure out the position of my scrollable table,and you were right to test the body rather than the whole table.